# Audio stream offset missing on Media Player

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-media-player

I'm using FFMpeg to output a video. Everything works fine, but when I played it on Windows Media Player, the offset I've set to the audio stream didn't work.
It plays the sound from the very beginning.(playing properly on VLC and PotPlayer)
How can I fix this?

My command is

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i test_%03d.png 
-itsoffset 10 -ss 5 -t 20 -i s01.wav
-c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg writes an edit list in the MP4 for offsets like these but Windows Media Player ignores them.

Use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i test_%03d.png 
-ss 5 -t 20 -i s01.wav -af "adelay=10000|10000"
-c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, delay worked! I'm not sure "edit list" will be ignored by other players or not, Had better use "adelay" over  "offset"?

Comment: Players like VLC, MPC do pay heed to it.

Comment: one further question, can I see the embedded edit list in the video file?